# ¿Como capturar un Object en la ruta (Route) del PUT en un controller?

Tags: c#, controller, object

es que tengo un PUT y quiero capturar el valor del campo que voy a actualizar, pero en la base de datos en un `SQL_Variant` asi que para hacerlo tengo que enviar un object al momento de enviar la a la base de datos, este es mi PUT

```
[HttpPut("{empid}/{codigo}/{valor}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int empid, string codigo, [FromRoute]object valor)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(await repository.UpdateAsync(empid, codigo, valor));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         return BadRequest(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Si yo aqui `[FromRoute]object valor` le cambio a string o a int me lo recibe correctamente, pero si lo dejo en tipo `Object` me llegara Null y pues no me sirve, ¿como hago para capturar un object desde la ruta del Controller?

Comment: Porque un object? es demasiado generico, no sabes que vas a recibir realmente?

Comment: Exacto, no se que voy a recibir, puede ser un booleano, una cadena, una fecha, etc

Comment: siempre en la url va a ser una cadena. ahora, no saber que vas a recibir es un problema. Porque vas a asumir, que es lo que estas recibiendo.. por ejemplo.. TRUE es una cadena o un booleano? y porque?

Comment: Si ante ese problema, habia pensado en un convertidor y esas cosas, pero pues dejare mas bien el valor que venga desde el Body con la etiqueta `[FromBody]string valor` y se la envio serializada en Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definelo como string y este recibira todos los tipos que envies, despues dentro del codigdo del controller podras castear para ver realmente de que tipo se trata

```
[HttpPut("{empid}/{codigo}/{valor}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int empid, string codigo, [FromRoute]string valor)
{
    try
    {
        object persistValor = valor;

        int numberValor;
        bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(valor, out numberValor);

        if(isNumeric)
        {
          persistValor = numberValor;
        }

        return Ok(await repository.UpdateAsync(empid, codigo, persistValor));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         return BadRequest(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

como veras deberas ver de que tipo se trata pera asignar el string que le llega o el valor que se convierte a numerico si es que es un numero

Se podria ver si se resuelve con un custom [ModelBinding](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1261/custom-model-binder-aspnet-mvc), pero lo veo dificil si el valor lo envias en la url, quizas si lo hicieras como parte del `body` del put